# post_content is empty

Tags: plugins, post-content

I'm trying to make some plugin. This plugin is some kind of auto posting.

```
function new_post($title,$content)
{
$post = get_post($id);
$feat_image = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );
$title = $post->post_title;
$content = $post->post_content;
echo $title;
echo $content;
}
add_action( 'publish_post', 'new_post' );
```

I can see only `$title`, `$content` is empty.

I've checked mysql in draft status, I can see `post_title` fields has data but `post_content` has no data.

`post_content` has data when I click publish or auto save. I think this plugin run faster than wordpress insert data process.

This plugin have to run after publish or make different way.

How can I fix this code...

I hope wordpress developer's can help.

Comment: Sorry, I can't tell what you are trying to do. What is the point of that code? What should it accomplish?

Comment: Where is `$id` coming from when looking for a post?

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to pass the post $id in the function and not $title and $content:

```
function new_post($id)
```

Then your function may be echoing the content - check your source code in your browser via "View Page Source" if it appears blank.

However, if you use `echo $content` then shortcodes, WordPress's formatting and password protection functions will all be broken. You need to wrap your call like this:

```
echo apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content);
```

More info on this [here](http://www.rescuework.jp/main/en_GB/wordpress-security-issues/do-not-echo-post-post_content.html) and [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/publish_post)

```
function new_post($post_ID)
{
$post = get_post($post_ID);
$feat_image = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );
$title = $post->post_title;
$content = $post->post_content;
echo $title;
echo apply_filters('the_content', $content);
}
add_action( 'publish_post', 'new_post' );
```

Also, if you're trying to grab the updated/changed info it will be stored in the `$_POST` variable. But if you grab info from `$post->post_content` that is the old info already stored in the database from before you save/publish/update your post. At some point you may also want a conditional statement to check if this is the first time you are publishing the page, or if it is being updated. Something like this:

```
if( ( $_POST['post_status'] == 'publish' ) && ( $_POST['original_post_status'] != 'publish' ) ) {
// code to execute here...
}
```